# Recursively getting body of email with Pyzmail module

Tags: python-3.x, email, imap

I'm trying to create an app that needs to recursively check an email address for new emails and then do some other stuff; I'm having some problems with the getting the body of the emails, though. I'm using the pyzmail module alongside imapclient, and the Automate the Boring Stuff for guidance (with python 3.6). Here's my code:

```
mail = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)
mail.login('email', 'password')
mail.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=False)
uid = mail.gmail_search('NC')
for i in uid:
   message = mail.fetch(i, ['BODY[]'], 'FLAGS')
   msg = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(message[i][b'BODY[]'])
   msg.html_part.get_payload().decode(msg.text_part.charset)
```

But it's not working. I've basically tried different forms of this code but to no avail and there's really not that many examples that can help me along. I'm a bit of a python newbie. Can anybody help?
Thanks,

**EDIT**

I realized where I made a mistake and fixed a bit of the code:

```
server = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)
server.login('p.imagery.serv@gmail.com', 'rabbitrun88ve')
server.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=True)
uids = server.gmail_search('NC')
for i in uids:
    messages = server.fetch(i, ['BODY[]'])
    msg = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(messages[b'BODY[]'])
```

The problem I'm having is with the last line, which I dont know how to fed using the variables that is created with the iterator. It throws out this message:

```
ValueError: input must be a string a bytes, a file or a Message
```

Comment: I don't see what you mean by 'recursive' here.  There is no recursion in your problem statement.

Comment: @Max I'm trying to pull the content of the emails that have the NC as subject. So if there's 3 emails with that subject, I want to pull that information. Example: if the content of one email is "Hello, this is a test" then that's all I would want. Perhaps I used the term recursively wrong. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still have this problem but for those who might have similar issues in future.
I noticed a little omission in the last line which might be the culprit.

```
msg = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(messages[b'BODY[]'])
```

You omitted the 'i' variable of the for loop

```
msg = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(messages[i][b'BODY[]'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to do next to get body text of searched messages:

```
    server = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', ssl=True)
    server.login('p.imagery.serv@gmail.com', 'rabbitrun88ve')
    server.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=True)
    uids = server.gmail_search('NC')
    rawmessage = server.fetch(uids, ['BODY[]'])
    for i in rawmessage:
        msg = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawmessage[i][b'BODY[]'])
        msg.html_part.get_payload().decode(msg.text_part.charset)
```

In this case, you get iteration over fetched emails with body text. I checked similar example but I used `text_part.get_payload()` instead `html` regarding features of my server.